# How ImageCell "Command property" and "Command Parameter" bind with viewModel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a ListView with ImageCell. I want to exicute a command on ImageCell click. But, debugger not call command method in ViewModel. 
(I do the same for button command , that is working.)

View:

```
    <ListView x:Name="lvLocation" ItemsSource="{Binding LocationList}">   
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ImageCell ImageSource="edit.png" Height="40" Text="{Binding StoreName}" Detail="{Binding CityName}" Command="{Binding OnImageListCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding CityName}"/>         
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>         
    </ListView>
```

View Model:

```
      public class ClassName: MvvmBaseClass
        {             

            public ICommand OnImageListCommand { get; set; }

            public ClassName()
            {                       
                OnImageListCommand = new Command<string>( OnImageListClick );
            }

            private void OnImageListClick(string _commandParamenter)
            {
                //Write code here.

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. What is the item's type in `LocationList`? Make sure that `LocationList` contains the items of type `ClassName`

The `ImageCell` will inherit the `BidningContext` from lvLocation's ItemSource

Comment: Here, LocationList is a Collection of class type. ImageCell Text and Details property successfully binded, but command and command property not binded with Icommand that I have created in its View Model. Don't know why, have you any solution for this ?

Comment: The `command` binds to the item in the collection, not the parent object. So your OnImageListCommand needs to be on each item in your collection, not in the ViewModel.

This is something I'm struggling with at the moment, and I don't like the idea of having of having a `Command` on each object in the collection.